# Regarding assumptions in typical Bayes' theorem problems

Tags: bayesian

This is **not** a question about how to understand [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). I have read textbooks and materials carefully and I think I understand it well. This is a question about the assumptions used in typical Bayes' theorem problems.

For example, the diagnostic test problem is a typical Bayes' theorem problem, which usually goes like this:

"A patient gets tested for a disease which afflicts 1% of population. The test is advertised as 95% accurate (meaning: P(T|D) = 0.95 and P(Tc|Dc) = 0.95, where T is test result is positive and D is the patient has the disease). Please calculate P(D|T)."

From what I read it seems that the problem is not just an exercise for students, instead it is from real cases. That's what I don't understand. My question is if we can gather past data to get P(T|D), why can't we just gather past data to get P(D|T) directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is if we can gather past data to get P(T|D), why can't we just gather past data to get P(D|T) directly?

#### In short

By not evaluating P(D|T) directly you make the experiments easier as you can vary the groups of D and Dc on which you perform the testing and gather the data. These groups do not need to be in the ratio 1:99

#### Easy experiment

The value of P(T|D) is often computed against some golden standard. For instance, you have some group of people with known D or Dc and you tabulate them

```
       D    Dc
T    950    50  1000        
Tc    50   950  1000
    1000  1000  2000
```

In this particular test we used data from, say, several hospitals which together have 1000 patients and they were compared with a group of 1000 healthy people.

So this is a simple way to determine P(T|D) and P(T|Dc).

#### Complex experiment

If you would like to determine P(D|T) directly **then you would need to select patients and sick people in a ratio equal to the prevalance**. So you could sample something like this:

```
     D      Dc
T   19      99    118        
Tc   1    1881   1882
    20    1980   2000
```

Then conclude that P(D|T) = 19/118 ≈ 0.16

But for such an experiment you will have only very few cases of D. So we better do the easier experiment for which the P(T|D) is more accurately determined.

#### Wrap up

You need a number of cases T given D in order to make good estimates. For this you need a sufficiently large group of D. But we would need 99 times more of the group Dc which would be a lot. Luckily we do not need to have so many Dc because we do not need to evaluate P(D|T) directly, as we have Bayes rule.

Comment: Hi Sextus, thanks for your answer. It's enlightening. But I suspect there might be something wrong with the your "Easy experiment" approach, because if I use the table in that experiment to calculate P(T|D), it would be 950/1000 = 0.95, which is wrong. So it seems we need to consider the 1% ratio of the D in "Easy experiment" also?

Comment: @rayx P(D|T) = 0.95 in the first experiment because the marginal distribution of D and T is 1:1 instead of 1:99 (the experiment is performed on a selected sample of people with the disease and healthy people). That is the point why we can not 'just gather past data to get to P(D|T) directly', it is because experiments are often not performed with a representative sample (the 'complex' experiment is performed like that, but you see that it is not very practical because either the sample with D is small giving low accuracy or the sample with T is large giving an expensive experiment)

Comment: Thanks! After thinking long and hard I finally get what you meant. If I understand it correctly, the key point is that P(D|Tc) in the second experiment is too low. As a result, one needs to gather tens of thousands of samples to get accurate data. BTW, it seems to me that it's not required to use representative sample even in the second experiment. For example, it should be fine if we select a T group of 118 people (19 with D + 99 with Dc) and a Tc group of 18820 people (10 with D + 18810 with Dc) for the second experiment. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: In these two experiments, you select a group with verified D and a group with verified Dc and on those you perform experiments to find out P(T|D) and P(T|Dc). You do not select a group with T or a Tc. The problem in the second experiment is that you stick to the ratio D:Dc of 1:99, which means a test that has either very small D (low accuracy of estimate) or very large Dc (high costs of the experiment). Note that the 1980 people with Dc is an overkill and unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Now the only question I have is about the sampling methodology for the second experiment (as you explained in the last comment). Why can't we just go to hospitals to get samples of people testing positive vs negative (that is, selecting a group with T or Tc)? I think that it should work too (though sample D in Tc group would be very small, so your point that the experiment is expensive still holds true).

Comment: Of course, if we perform the second experiment by selecting a group of T and a group of Tc, we need to estimate P(D|T) and P(Dc|Tc) ahead to plan the sample size. That is, the design of the experiment depends on the values to which the experiment is intended to get. But I think the same holds true for the first experiment, right? Please note that I don't have statistics background (I'm learning it by myself).

Comment: @rayx it depends on the situation. The method that you describe, **selecting T and Tc**, is probably done for a test that is already being used in the field, and one does an extensive search on selected groups with $T$ and $Tc$ to see how much $D$ and $Dc$ they have. The problem here is that you may have a selection effect and you need to be sure that these $T$ and $Tc$ are generated by a process with 1:99 D:Dc (with the covid PCR testing this is a problem, if you limit testing to mostly sick people with symptoms because of limitations in number of tests, then the ratio D:Dc) ....

Comment: ... the method that I described, **selecting D and Dc**, is a test that is more usefull for a test that is not yet applied in the field (so you do not have groups of people with T and Tc that you can select from). The group of D and Dc might be patients (with verified D according to some expensive 'golden standard' test) and healthy people (with verified Dc).

Comment: What you said all make sense! I wasn't aware that, in the approach I proposed (selecting T and Tc), I still have to make sure that, for the **total** people in T and Tc groups, the D:Dc ratio should be 1:99. And the way to do that is exactly the approach you described in your second experiment.

Comment: Now I find I come back to my original question: why do we have to consider the 1:99 D:Dc ratio in your second experiment but not in your first experiment? This time I realize the answer is actually very simple: in the first experiment the data is used to calculate P(T|D), so the ratio of D:Dc doesn't really matter. But in the second experiment that data is used to  calculate P(D|T), so the ratio matters. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, so the Bayes theorem allows us to compute P(D|T) from experiments with different D:Dc ratio's than the D:Dc ratio from the population for which we wish to compute P(D|T).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the discussion. It has been very helpful.